# Parsing jsoup in list gets wrong results

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-listview, jsoup

I'm parsing this page http://twixkat.altervista.org/download.html the table tag. This is what i'm doing:

```
private class SearchResult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

String resultTextFmt;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FragmentThree.this);
mProgressDialog.setTitle("Twix Updates");
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.show();
titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
descrizioni = new ArrayList<String>();
url = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
try {

Document document =Jsoup.connect(URL.toString()).get();
// prendo gli elementi che mi interessano dalla tabella
Elements description2 = document.select("#rom_table");
for(Element sezione : description2)//per ogni sezione tra gli elementi ricavati prima
{
// ricavo il titolo
// (con .text() ottengo il testo non formattato
String titolo = sezione.select("tr").text();

String descrizione = sezione.select("a").text();

//-- mi prendo il link
String urldesc = sezione.select("a").first().attr("abs:href");

// inserisco nei rispettivi arraylist

titoli.add(titolo);
descrizioni.add(descrizione);
url.add(urldesc);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
/*Toast.makeText(FragmentThree.this, "Errore parsing",
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    Log.d("errore", "errore parsing");
}
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

/*textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(resultTextFmt));*/
/*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), resultTextFmt,
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(FragmentThree.this, titoli, descrizioni);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
mProgressDialog.dismiss();  
}

}
```

It works but not exactly as i want... It gives me only one item in the list and in the `titolo` i have all `tr` tags.. What i want is two items in the list, first one with title: `LG Nexus 4  Alpha (04/18/2014)` and second `LG Nexus 5  Alpha (04/19/2014)`... and not like now that these two stuffs are in a single row. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `getElementById` to retrieve the `rom_table` from the parsed `Document` and then get the `Elements` by tag `tr`.

```
  final  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://twixkat.altervista.org/download.html").get();
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
            public void run() {
                 Element rootElement = doc.body().getElementById("rom_table");
                 Elements elements = rootElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
                 for(Element element : elements){
                     String titolo = element.select("tr").text();
                     String descrizione = element.select("a").text();
                     String urldesc = element.select("a").first().attr("abs:href");
                      // do your other stuff here to add to List
                        }
                    }
                });
```